# Help to implement if-statement with array values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a following source code php+js: http://pastebin.org/277948

I want to rewrite it using pure JS, but can’t imagine the way.

Any advices are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test if all elements in the array satisfy the predicate.

```
if (inp && vals.every(Boolean)) {
  // or:  vals.every(function(x){return x;})
  ...
}
```

But if you have to target browsers that does not support the `every` method, you can evaluate the condition with a for loop.

```
if (inp) {
   accept = true;
   for (var i = vals.length-1; i >= 0; -- i)
     if (!vals[i]) {
       accept = false;
       break;
     }
   if (accept) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, all browsers support 'every' method'. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

sorry dont know php but this is the javascript.

```
if (inp == true) {
   for(i =0;i<numFields; i++){
     do something with vals[i];
   }
}
```